Can I use the subdomain in an address as a web service when the domain name itself contains a subdomain?
So I got my domain name from NoIP, and the name was X.Y.net. So when I got a domain name it included a subdomain, right? So when you have multiple web services on one physical host usually I've seen people use the subdomain to distinguish the service as route to another server based on that, but in this case my domain name that is mapped to my home ISP-provided IP has a subdomain already (the X in X.Y.net). So can I use a reverse proxy such as Nginx to use another subdomain deeper in the tree to route to different services, like A.X.Y.net and B.X.Y.net?
Because the domain name I got from NoIP is X.Y.net then it's a subdomain, not a domain, right? I mean when the DNS lookup is done is it the Y.net that's mapped to my IP address and the X subdomain is just appended to it as a matter of the hostname when you get HTTP requests etc., or is the DNS lookup mapping the entire (X.Y.net) to my IP address?

X.Y.net is a domain that points at your IP. Period. End of story. If you want to use FOO.X.Y.net for something, you need to have it point to your IP as well. Whether NoIP will let you register/configure that specific domain is the real question.

@deceze I see, so if I want to host two services then I can't have it on A.X.Y.net unless I register that with the DNS? That's weird I'm pretty sure I've seen people do that. So you're saying that if someone types A.X.Y.net into the browser the DNS resolution won't even succeed (route to my IP)?

Right. If that domain isn’t registered, the DNS lookup will fail.

@deceze So how do I host two services through a reverse proxy like Nginx with only that domain name? I have to utilise the URI differentiation to pull that off? ie., anything after .net/service1 .net/service2

Yes, you can use additional subdomains like A.X.Y.net and B.X.Y.net! You would typically do this by configuring your NoIP account to create these additional subdomains and map them to your IP address.
For example, you would create two more A records in your NoIP settings:
A.X.Y.net -> Your IP
B.X.Y.net -> Your IP
you could configure Nginx to direct traffic:
A.X.Y.net to Service A (e.g., localhost:8000)
B.X.Y.net to Service B (e.g., localhost:8001)
Here’s a basic example of what your Nginx configuration could look like:
server {  
    listen 80;  
    server_name A.X.Y.net;  

    location / {  
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;  
        # other proxy settings  
    }  
}  

server {  
    listen 80;  
    server_name B.X.Y.net;  

    location / {  
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;  
        # other proxy settings  
    }  
} 

If you don't want to map subdomains to your IP address, you can not use it.

So you have to map additional subdomains with the DNS registrar then, cool. Thank you.

I've noticed in some example when they do proxy pass instead off doing http they do fastcgi? Do you know the differences are? I've seen that fastcgi is a lighter protocol and so it may be a good reason to use that from the reverse proxy to the web server, however http seems to be more common.

Yes, it is. If you're building a high-performance web application and you have the ability to utilize FastCGI, it can be the better choice compared to traditional HTTP proxying. However, HTTP is still the more commonly used method for many web applications due to its simplicity and wide support.
